# CMS GC running every second with abort preclean due to time

Tags: java, garbage-collection

And also what we observer Work set of the process running very high and its not coming down too,,

Just im Here is a copy of the GC log below, and my GC parameter, parameters. Please can you some one suggest to me 
- Why work set went high for this process and not coming down (its 2.2GB around now) 
- Is there any issue with my GC parameter or setting, :

JAVA 1.5 64-bit

```
   *-Xnoclassgc -XX:+AggressiveOpts  -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC   -XX:PermSize=24m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m  -XX:SurvivorRatio=2  -XX:MaxNewSize=96m  -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20  -XX:NewRatio=3  
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xms128m -Xmx2048m*


    *2015-03-25 09:03:47,664:::229547.664: [GC 229547.664: [ParNew: 53900K->4741K(73728K), 0.0262695 secs] 1972769K->1923679K(2072576K), 0.0264483 secs]*
```

and CMS -

```
2015-03-25 19:08:12,187:::265812.187: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1951263K(1998848K)] 1982060K(2072576K), 0.0100608 secs]
2015-03-25 19:08:12,198:::265812.198: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2015-03-25 19:08:14,469:::265814.469: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 2.271/2.271 secs]
2015-03-25 19:08:14,469:::265814.469: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2015-03-25 19:08:14,475:::265814.475: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.006/0.006 secs]
2015-03-25 19:08:14,475:::265814.475: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2015-03-22 17:18:00,000::: CMS: abort preclean due to time 265815.512: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.099/1.038 secs]
2015-03-25 19:08:15,513:::265815.513: [GC[YG occupancy: 31752 K (73728 K)]265815.514: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0196751 secs]265815.533: [weak refs processing, 0.0000057 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 1951263K(1998848K)] 1983016K(2072576K), 0.0197838 secs]*
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834501/abort-preclean-due-to-time-in-concurrent-mark-sweep